# What are the rules for using qualified names in friend declarations?

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend

The following code produces a compile error (on a recent version of gcc at least):

```
namespace a {

class X { friend void ::foo(); };

}
```

The error is:

```
'void foo()' should have been declared inside '::'
```

If we remove `::` from the declaration, according to the standard, `foo` will be introduced into the namespace `a` (although it won't be visible). Predeclaring foo inside of `a` is not required.

My question is, given the above, why is predeclaring within the global namespace a requirement? Why doesn't the name `foo` become a member of the global namespace? I couldn't find any paragraph in the standard that would explicitly forbid that either, so I'm curious to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph you're looking for is [dcl.meaning] (8.3 (1) in C++11):

> (...) A *declarator-id* shall not be qualified except for the definition of a member function or static data member outside of its class, the definition or explicit instantiation of a function or variable of a namespace outside of its namespace, or the definition of an explicit specialization outside of its namespace, or the declaration of a friend function that is a member of another class or namespace. **When the *declarator-id* is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member of the class or namespace to which the qualifier refers** (or, in the case of a namespace, of an element of the inline namespace set of that namespace).

(emphasis mine) What this means is that you cannot write

```
namespace a { }

void a::foo() { }
```

unless `a::foo` is already declared with an unqualified declarator inside the namespace. And since there is no exception for friends, you cannot do this for friends either.

A footnote in [namespace.memdef] (7.3.1.2 (3) in C++11) mentions this even more explicitly for the special case of friends:

> (...) If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class or function<sup>95</sup> the friend class or function is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. (...)
>
> <sup>95)</sup> This implies that the name of the class or function is unqualified.